# Aircrack-ng problem with Ralink RT2800 USB wifi - is driver compatible?

Tags: atheros, ralink, aircrack-ng

This is the info I get running `modinfo rt2800usb`. While running Airodump-ng with wlan0(ath9k driver) or wlan2(tplink 722n-ar9271 chipset/ath9k driver) in monitor mode I am able to get Station MAC address when running: `airodump-ng -c 11 --bssid MA:CA:DD:RE:SS` wlan0/2 within seconds. Yet while running same code with an rt5370 rt3070 usb the Station MAC ADDRESS doesn't show(after 90min). Is the rt2800usb driver installed correctly or is the driver not compatible with Aircrack? I've read all over the net that the rt2800usb drivers/chipsets and ath9k driver/chipset are compatible so why am I not seeing the Station MAC ADDRESS after code `airodump-ng -c 2 --bssid MA:CA:DD:RE:SS`?

```
modinfo rt2800usb
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2870.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 USB Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     28DAD2AE9E9BE23174C63CF
alias:          usb:vF201p5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0254d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApF511d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApD522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApC522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA512d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0078d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p006Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0069d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0053d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p004Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p004Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v08B9p1197d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v18E8p6259d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB29d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB24d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp0010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v05A6p0101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v100Dp9032d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0169d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0168d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0615d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0605d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp094Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148FpF101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v06F8pE036d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1044p800Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15A9p0010d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0602d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p0600d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v203Dp14A1d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v18C5p0008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp0042d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp0041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0150d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0148d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p012Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3401d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3400d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3399d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3340d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3322d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3284d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3262d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17A7d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1790d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1761d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1760d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p166Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E0Bp9041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E0Bp9031d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C11d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C08d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3074d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3073d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20F4p724Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5572d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A13d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C21d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0253d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0241d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v057Cp8501d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5372d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp5370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2182d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2181d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2180d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2126d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p2104d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04DAp23F6d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04DAp1800d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04DAp1801d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A42d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A22d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C23d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C22d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C20d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C19d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C15d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3365d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3329d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17E8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A32d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep7A12d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3421d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p006Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p006Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0067d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3573d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pED19d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9019d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9013d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0846p9012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p016Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p003Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp094Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0021d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0020d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7733d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148FpF301d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp1103d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17ADd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p17BCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p7733d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0284d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0930p0A07d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0068d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0066d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0065d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0062d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0041d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3572d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0170d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0079d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p002Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0944d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9801d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v167Bp4001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p179Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0764d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0761d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0744d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3572d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0165d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0163d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0050d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp8070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3370d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p20DDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApB511d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp945Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p343Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p341Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p341Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3418d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0586p3416d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p5257d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0283d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0282d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v5A57p0280d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CDEp0025d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0CDEp0022d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v157Ep3013d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v157Ep300Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0324d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0323d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0313d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0302d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0164d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v177Fp0153d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15A9p0006d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApB522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA703d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA702d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA701d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083ApA618d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap8522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap7522d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap7512d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap7511d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v083Ap6618d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0060d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p005Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0051d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0048d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0047d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0042d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0040d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p003Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0039d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p002Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p002Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p002Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DF6p0017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v129Bp1828d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04E8p2018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp2770d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v148Fp2070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1A32p0304d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pED06d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019pAB25d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2019p5201d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0471p200Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp0011d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp000Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp000Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1D4Dp0002d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v20B8p8888d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75pA200d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1B75p3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p899Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p871Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p871Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p871Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p870Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p822Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p822Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p822Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p821Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p6899d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3871d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3822d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3821d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0DB0p3820d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v100Dp9031d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0166d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0164d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0163d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0789p0162d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0078d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0077d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1737p0070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p0031d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0948d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0947d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04BBp0945d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0018d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0017d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0013d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p000Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0009d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0003d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0E66p0001d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1044p800Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1044p800Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15A9p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9709d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9708d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9707d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9706d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9705d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9703d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9702d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1740p9701d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v203Dp14A9d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v203Dp1480d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7722d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7718d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7717d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p7711d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392p4085d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0FE9pB307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07FAp7712d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C25d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3C1Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v2001p3317d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C16d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C15d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C13d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C11d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C0Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07D1p3C09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v18C5p0012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp003Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp003Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07AAp002Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01FDd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01A8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01EEd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p01A2d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p016Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p015Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p0158d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0411p00E8d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp935Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp935Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp825Bd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp825Ad*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp815Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp805Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v050Dp8053d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3321d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3307d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3305d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3273d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13D3p3247d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1761p0B05d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1784d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1742d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1732d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0B05p1731d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1690p0740d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v15C5p0008d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C2Cd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C28d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C27d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C25d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C23d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C12d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C07d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v14B2p3C06d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p2770d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v8516p2070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1EDAp2310d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1EDAp2210d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1EDAp2012d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v1482p3C09d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3072d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3071d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p3070d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p2770d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v07B8p2870d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.2.0-42-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        E1:78:61:78:9C:2D:8F:1B:8F:C3:6C:CA:1B:40:2A:6D:F7:B7:EE:A8
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)
```

Comment: using chipsets: rt3070 and rt5370